# Как проверить наличие leaks используя SDL2 с "C Run-time Library" или "Dr. Memory"

Tags: c, память, visual-studio-2017, утечка-памяти, sdl2

В моем роспоряжении были IDE (Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community), библиотека SDL2, и CRT (C Run-time Library). Код для тестирования.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF | _CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF | _CRTDBG_CHECK_CRT_DF);
    _CrtMemState s1;
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&s1);

    SDL_Window      *window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer    *renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Event       event;
    const uint8_t   *cur_key;
    char            *win_name = "demo_name";
    int8_t          loop = 1;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
        printf("ERROR! SDL_INIT\n");
    else
    {
        if (!(window = SDL_CreateWindow(win_name, 200, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN)))
        {
            printf("ERROR! CREATED WINDOWS FAIL\n");
            loop = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!(renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC)))
            {
                printf("ERROR! CREATED RENDERER FAIL\n");
                loop = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    while (loop)
    {
        SDL_PollEvent(&event);
        cur_key = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            loop = 0;
        if (cur_key[SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE])
            loop = 0;
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 0);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
    if (renderer)
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    if (window)
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Окно вывода предоставляет мне вот такой отчет:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\internal\per_thread_data.cpp(242) : {106} crt block at 0x0163AB10, subtype 0, 1736 bytes long.
 Data: <p               > 70 1F 92 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\internal\per_thread_data.cpp(242) : {101} crt block at 0x08595350, subtype 0, 1736 bytes long.
 Data: <p               > 70 1F 92 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\internal\per_thread_data.cpp(242) : {89} crt block at 0x0168A6D8, subtype 0, 1736 bytes long.
 Data: <p               > 70 1F 92 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\internal\per_thread_data.cpp(242) : {85} crt block at 0x01659108, subtype 0, 1736 bytes long.
 Data: <p               > 70 1F 92 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\internal\per_thread_data.cpp(242) : {83} crt block at 0x016562C8, subtype 0, 1736 bytes long.
 Data: <p               > 70 1F 92 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\lowio\osfinfo.cpp(17) : {2} crt block at 0x0163B208, subtype 0, 3584 bytes long.
 Data: <                > FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

в случае коментарования фунций деструкторов `SDL_DestroyRenderer()` и `SDL_DestroyWindow()` ситуация ухудшается

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\internal\per_thread_data.cpp(242) : {106} crt block at 0x00E3A468, subtype 0, 1736 bytes long.
 Data: <p 1             > 70 1F 31 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\internal\per_thread_data.cpp(242) : {105} crt block at 0x0CB789F0, subtype 0, 1736 bytes long.
 Data: <p 1             > 70 1F 31 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\internal\per_thread_data.cpp(242) : {103} crt block at 0x0860EAE8, subtype 0, 1736 bytes long.
 Data: <p 1             > 70 1F 31 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\internal\per_thread_data.cpp(242) : {101} crt block at 0x086003D8, subtype 0, 1736 bytes long.
 Data: <p 1             > 70 1F 31 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\internal\per_thread_data.cpp(242) : {99} crt block at 0x085D3ED0, subtype 0, 1736 bytes long.
 Data: <p 1             > 70 1F 31 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\internal\per_thread_data.cpp(242) : {97} crt block at 0x085D2D10, subtype 0, 1736 bytes long.
 Data: <p 1             > 70 1F 31 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\internal\per_thread_data.cpp(242) : {95} crt block at 0x085C07D8, subtype 0, 1736 bytes long.
 Data: <p 1             > 70 1F 31 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\internal\per_thread_data.cpp(242) : {93} crt block at 0x085BEA40, subtype 0, 1736 bytes long.
 Data: <p 1             > 70 1F 31 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\internal\per_thread_data.cpp(242) : {89} crt block at 0x00E8DEC8, subtype 0, 1736 bytes long.
 Data: <p 1             > 70 1F 31 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\internal\per_thread_data.cpp(242) : {85} crt block at 0x00E5ACD8, subtype 0, 1736 bytes long.
 Data: <p 1             > 70 1F 31 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\internal\per_thread_data.cpp(242) : {83} crt block at 0x00E566C0, subtype 0, 1736 bytes long.
 Data: <p 1             > 70 1F 31 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\lowio\osfinfo.cpp(17) : {2} crt block at 0x00E3AB60, subtype 0, 3584 bytes long.
 Data: <                > FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

1) Как отследить выделения памяти не использующие malloc?
2) Как определить на какую память указывают отчеты?
P.S. Если у вас есть советы по менеджменту памяти в Win10 буду благодарен за совет.

**Обновление:**
Урезав саму код, до не приличного, и испольщзовав "Dr. Memory"

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

получил результат в виде

```
Error #1: LEAK 264 direct bytes 0x02c356e0-0x02c357e8 + 0 indirect bytes
# 0 replace_RtlAllocateHeap                     [d:\drmemory_package\common\alloc_replace.c:3770]
# 1 combase.dll!RoRegisterActivationFactories  +0x2e0a   (0x74268ebb <combase.dll+0x98ebb>)
# 2 combase.dll!CoMarshalInterface             +0x34a6   (0x74281447 <combase.dll+0xb1447>)
# 3 combase.dll!CoInitializeEx                 +0x34     (0x742b4ae5 <combase.dll+0xe4ae5>)
# 4 SDL2.dll!?                                 +0x0      (0x6c7f69ee <SDL2.dll+0xb69ee>)
# 5 SDL2.dll!?                                 +0x0      (0x6c807c5a <SDL2.dll+0xc7c5a>)
# 6 SDL2.dll!?                                 +0x0      (0x6c8063d5 <SDL2.dll+0xc63d5>)
# 7 SDL2.dll!?                                 +0x0      (0x6c747930 <SDL2.dll+0x7930>)
# 8 SDL2.dll!?                                 +0x0      (0x6c74187e <SDL2.dll+0x187e>)
# 9 KERNEL32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk           +0x23     (0x73868484 <KERNEL32.dll+0x18484>)
```

Так что к двум предыдущим вопросам добавлю еще один...
3) Как избавится от утечки вормируемой сомой SDL2? (если я не правильно трактую имеющуюся у меня информацию, поправте меня)
На всякий случай прилогаю **FINAL SUMMARY:**

```
ERRORS FOUND:
      0 unique,     0 total unaddressable access(es)
      0 unique,     0 total uninitialized access(es)
      0 unique,     0 total invalid heap argument(s)
      0 unique,     0 total GDI usage error(s)
      0 unique,     0 total handle leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total warning(s)
      1 unique,     1 total,    264 byte(s) of leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of possible leak(s)
ERRORS IGNORED:
     52 potential error(s) (suspected false positives)
     15 potential leak(s) (suspected false positives)
    361 unique,   483 total,  93492 byte(s) of still-reachable allocation(s)
```

Comment: Dr.Memory, фактически аналог Valgrind https://www.drmemory.org

Comment: @NewView попробовал данную утилиту, но так и не смог полностью с ней разобраться, если у вас есть ссылки на гайды буду очень благодарен. Да и сути она не решила... Как исключить _leaks_ если не знаешь какая функция к этому приводит?

Comment: А чего в ней разбираться, она с ключами запускается и в выходном каталоге создаёт текстовые файлы отчётов, весьма подробные. Если нужно ключи запуска, то могу привести пример, хотя там по моему и так всё ясно. Лучше создайте отдельную тему, я тогда по теме там приведу пример запуска.

Comment: `исключить leaks если не знаешь какая функция` - там всё подробно написано с номером строки, именем функции итд

Comment: Судя по последнему логу, с памятью все в порядке. То что там выделяется SDL2 вероятно будет убито при выгрузке самой библиотеки, мне кажется что беспокоиться не о чем.

Comment: @NewView Дело в том что експеремнтальным путем удается добавить подобных ликов. К примеру не используя функции деструкторы библиотеки, но Dr.Memory все равно диагностирует утечки в стороних местах, а не в моём приложении. Что оставляет меня в недоумении... Я конечно могу запомнить эти "пару ликов" как допустимые, и пойти дальше, но это не страхуеть меня от неправильного использования библиотеки... И по идее выгрузка самой библиотеки должна происходить после `SDL_Quit()`...

Comment: Выгрузка всей библиотеки (любой) происходит при закрытии приложения или через  вызов `FreeLibrary`.  А то что вы видите в памяти это результат работы `LoadLibrary`, в принципе возможно вызывать `FreeLibrary` но это как правило избыточно, приложение все равно закрывается и все ресурсы закрываются автоматически и возвращаются системе.